# How to create popover in Xamarin iOS (iPhone)?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am creating a page where on click of a button a popover should appear as that in screenshot attached.
I have almost tried many methods to do so.but all ended up showing full screen.Is there really not any way to create a popover in Xamarin iOS?

Can any one help me with this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqm30.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can construct the custom pop view controller, then present it with the [UIModalPresentationStyle](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIModalPresentationStyle/)  `Popover`:

```
//The pop view controller you want to show, here I use Storyboard to initialize it
PopoverViewController popViewController = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("PopoverViewController") as PopoverViewController;

//Set the presentation style to popover
popViewController.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover;
//The popover view's size
popViewController.PreferredContentSize = new CGSize(150, 150);

//The pop view's position
popViewController.PopoverPresentationController.SourceView = MyBtn;
popViewController.PopoverPresentationController.SourceRect = MyBtn.Bounds;
popViewController.PopoverPresentationController.PermittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.Up;
//We can also customize the background color
//popViewController.PopoverPresentationController.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;

popViewController.PopoverPresentationController.Delegate = new PopOverViewDelegate();
PresentModalViewController(popViewController, true);
```

Do not forget to set the delegate below to achieve the same effect on iPhone:

```
public class PopOverViewDelegate : UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate
{
    public override UIModalPresentationStyle GetAdaptivePresentationStyle(UIPresentationController forPresentationController)
    {
        return UIModalPresentationStyle.None;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But it is not working for me.There is no action on click of the button.

Comment: @BBB I make a sample [here](https://github.com/landl0526/NativePopOverViewDemo) for you.